# npm install -g @vue/cli get error VUE CLI INSTALL ERROR

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I'm on PC/Windows 10, node15.0.0, npm 6.14.8

I just wanted to install Vue CLI and I got this error.

I have the latest version of Node.js as you can see below. I tried some different ways like `npm uninstall -g vue-cli` and `npm cache clean --force`, but, it did not work.

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging',
npm ERR!   parent: '@babel/core'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lixin yang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-31T14_42_05_231Z-debug.log
```

Any idea what that means and how to solve it?

I found that I could do nothing but press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Possible fixes:

1. open cmd as administrator - search for cmd, right-click, and open as administrator.
2. run this command `npm cache clean --force`
3. npm install again in this administrator cmd.

if still didn't work, close all node processes and try these steps again, also can try these after a system restart.

Comment: Thanks,my computer has been downloaded successfully vue/cli